# why & becomes &amp:amp; and how to solve this in XML?

Tags: java, xml

I am using below tag to query the item from DB. The item presents in DB but not showing up because `A&M` became as `A&amp;amp;M` instead of `A&amp;M`. How to solve this?

```
<TEA>2720A 100 STATE A&amp;amp;M RD VRAD</TEA>
```

A backend java code queries the item from DB like 'select * from aa where tea=2720A 100 STATE A&amp;M RD VRAD' and returns no record but it is present in DB like A&M. This is the exact issue, how to solve this?

Comment: Show us your Java code.

Comment: That's how xml works - any standard xml parser should parse `&amp;` as `&`.

Comment: Basically, we can't solve this without seeing every detail of your system. The data is being escaped twice, but to work out why, you need to study the complete dataflow in fine detail. I know it's unhelpful, but this isn't the kind of problem where StackOverflow helps much: we can't ask you to post the piece of code where the bug is, because your challenge is finding that piece of code.

Comment: Michael, in what cases the data gets encoded ?, i am sending another data like this which gets encoded once(correctly) in this same flow,is that affecting this to encode twice?

Answer (score 2):

Double encoding, your string is encoded twice.

```
First encoding A&M -> A&amp*M
Second encoding A&amp*M -> A&amp*amp*M
```

Check your code for this issue

Comment: Thanks :) . is there any way to avoid this by modifying data?

Answer (score 0):

Of course representing `&` in XML is done with `&amp;`.

- If just text is stored in the DB, for instance extracted fron between two tags `<name>A&amp;M</name>`, then any XML API should give `"A&M"` to be stored.
- If entire XML is stored in the DB, one should store it as-is: `"<name>A&amp;M</name>"`

The problem arises only when String manipulations are done. Say

```
String xml = "<name>A&amp;M</name>";
String name = xml.replaceFirst("^.*<name>(.*)</name>.*$", "$1");
name = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXML(name);
```

Here apache StringEscapeUtils is used. Not unescaping makes trouble.

It probably goes wrong, when mixing extracted text (should-be-unescaped text) with XML manipulation (DOM). And again placing it in an XML structure. The XML APIs in general return values with the entities unescaped, and escape the XML characters `<>&"'` to entities.

Especially be careful when editing in HTML, that uses the same entity; not showing the actual characters. Here `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4` comes into play.